# Inserting list inside a table causes an error Something's wrong--perhaps a missing

Tags: tables, itemize

I need to insert a bullet list inside the table columns but I get the output does not have the bullets and it throws back en error:

**LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
There are no entries found in a list you have created. Make sure you label list entries using the \item command, and that you have not used a list inside a table.**

```
%  LaTeX support: latex@mdpi.com 
%  For support, please attach all files needed for compiling as well as the log file, and specify your operating system, LaTeX version, and LaTeX editor.

%=================================================================
\documentclass[journal,article,submit,moreauthors,pdftex]{Definitions/mdpi} %sensors

% For posting an early version of this manuscript as a preprint, you may use "preprints" as the journal and change "submit" to "accept". The document class line would be, e.g., \documentclass[preprints,article,accept,moreauthors,pdftex]{mdpi}. This is especially recommended for submission to arXiv, where line numbers should be removed before posting. For preprints.org, the editorial staff will make this change immediately prior to posting.

%--------------------
% Class Options:
%--------------------
%----------
% journal
%----------
% Choose between the following MDPI journals:
% acoustics, actuators, addictions, admsci, adolescents, aerospace, agriculture, agriengineering, agronomy, ai, algorithms, allergies, analytica, animals, antibiotics, antibodies, antioxidants, appliedchem, applmech, applmicrobiol, applnano, applsci, arts, asi, atmosphere, atoms, audiolres, automation, axioms, batteries, bdcc, behavsci, beverages, biochem, bioengineering, biologics, biology, biomechanics, biomedicines, biomedinformatics, biomimetics, biomolecules, biophysica, biosensors, biotech, birds, bloods, brainsci, buildings, businesses, cancers, carbon, cardiogenetics, catalysts, cells, ceramics, challenges, chemengineering, chemistry, chemosensors, chemproc, children, civileng, cleantechnol, climate, clinpract, clockssleep, cmd, coatings, colloids, compounds, computation, computers, condensedmatter, conservation, constrmater, cosmetics, crops, cryptography, crystals, curroncol, cyber, dairy, data, dentistry, dermato, dermatopathology, designs, diabetology, diagnostics, digital, disabilities, diseases, diversity, dna, drones, dynamics, earth, ebj, ecologies, econometrics, economies, education, ejihpe, electricity, electrochem, electronicmat, electronics, encyclopedia, endocrines, energies, eng, engproc, entropy, environments, environsciproc, epidemiologia, epigenomes, fermentation, fibers, fire, fishes, fluids, foods, forecasting, forensicsci, forests, fractalfract, fuels, futureinternet, futuretransp, futurepharmacol, futurephys, galaxies, games, gases, gastroent, gastrointestdisord, gels, genealogy, genes, geographies, geohazards, geomatics, geosciences, geotechnics, geriatrics, hazardousmatters, healthcare, hearts, hemato, heritage, highthroughput, histories, horticulturae, humanities, hydrogen, hydrology, hygiene, idr, ijerph, ijfs, ijgi, ijms, ijns, ijtm, ijtpp, immuno, informatics, information, infrastructures, inorganics, insects, instruments, inventions, iot, j, jcdd, jcm, jcp, jcs, jdb, jfb, jfmk, jimaging, jintelligence, jlpea, jmmp, jmp, jmse, jne, jnt, jof, joitmc, jor, journalmedia, jox, jpm, jrfm, jsan, jtaer, jzbg, kidney, land, languages, laws, life, liquids, literature, livers, logistics, lubricants, machines, macromol, magnetism, magnetochemistry, make, marinedrugs, materials, materproc, mathematics, mca, measurements, medicina, medicines, medsci, membranes, metabolites, metals, metrology, micro, microarrays, microbiolres, micromachines, microorganisms, minerals, mining, modelling, molbank, molecules, mps, mti, nanoenergyadv, nanomanufacturing, nanomaterials, ncrna, network, neuroglia, neurolint, neurosci, nitrogen, notspecified, nri, nursrep, nutrients, obesities, oceans, ohbm, onco, oncopathology, optics, oral, organics, osteology, oxygen, parasites, parasitologia, particles, pathogens, pathophysiology, pediatrrep, pharmaceuticals, pharmaceutics, pharmacy, philosophies, photochem, photonics, physchem, physics, physiolsci, plants, plasma, pollutants, polymers, polysaccharides, proceedings, processes, prosthesis, proteomes, psych, psychiatryint, publications, quantumrep, quaternary, qubs, radiation, reactions, recycling, regeneration, religions, remotesensing, reports, reprodmed, resources, risks, robotics, safety, sci, scipharm, sensors, separations, sexes, signals, sinusitis, smartcities, sna, societies, socsci, soilsystems, solids, sports, standards, stats, stresses, surfaces, surgeries, suschem, sustainability, symmetry, systems, taxonomy, technologies, telecom, textiles, thermo, tourismhosp, toxics, toxins, transplantology, traumas, tropicalmed, universe, urbansci, uro, vaccines, vehicles, vetsci, vibration, viruses, vision, water, wevj, women, world 

%---------
% article
%---------
% The default type of manuscript is "article", but can be replaced by: 
% abstract, addendum, article, book, bookreview, briefreport, casereport, comment, commentary, communication, conferenceproceedings, correction, conferencereport, entry, expressionofconcern, extendedabstract, datadescriptor, editorial, essay, erratum, hypothesis, interestingimage, obituary, opinion, projectreport, reply, retraction, review, perspective, protocol, shortnote, studyprotocol, systematicreview, supfile, technicalnote, viewpoint, guidelines, registeredreport, tutorial
% supfile = supplementary materials

%----------
% submit
%----------
% The class option "submit" will be changed to "accept" by the Editorial Office when the paper is accepted. This will only make changes to the frontpage (e.g., the logo of the journal will get visible), the headings, and the copyright information. Also, line numbering will be removed. Journal info and pagination for accepted papers will also be assigned by the Editorial Office.

%------------------
% moreauthors
%------------------
% If there is only one author the class option oneauthor should be used. Otherwise use the class option moreauthors.

%---------
% pdftex
%---------
% The option pdftex is for use with pdfLaTeX. If eps figures are used, remove the option pdftex and use LaTeX and dvi2pdf.

%=================================================================
% MDPI internal commands
\firstpage{1} 
\makeatletter 
\setcounter{page}{\@firstpage} 
\makeatother
\pubvolume{1}
\issuenum{1}
\articlenumber{0}
\pubyear{2021}
\copyrightyear{2020}
%\externaleditor{Academic Editor: Firstname Lastname} % For journal Automation, please change Academic Editor to "Communicated by"
\datereceived{} 
\dateaccepted{} 
\datepublished{} 
\hreflink{https://doi.org/} % If needed use \linebreak
%------------------------------------------------------------------
% The following line should be uncommented if the LaTeX file is uploaded to arXiv.org
%\pdfoutput=1

%=================================================================
% Add packages and commands here. The following packages are loaded in our class file: fontenc, inputenc, calc, indentfirst, fancyhdr, graphicx, epstopdf, lastpage, ifthen, lineno, float, amsmath, setspace, enumitem, mathpazo, booktabs, titlesec, etoolbox, tabto, xcolor, soul, multirow, microtype, tikz, totcount, changepage, paracol, attrib, upgreek, cleveref, amsthm, hyphenat, natbib, hyperref, footmisc, url, geometry, newfloat, caption
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{ltablex}

\usepackage{graphicx,rotating,booktabs}
\usepackage{supertabular,booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{amssymb}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amssymb
\usepackage{pifont}

%\newcommand{\item}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}

%=================================================================
%% Please use the following mathematics environments: Theorem, Lemma, Corollary, Proposition, Characterization, Property, Problem, Example, ExamplesandDefinitions, Hypothesis, Remark, Definition, Notation, Assumption
%% For proofs, please use the proof environment (the amsthm package is loaded by the MDPI class).

%=================================================================
% Full title of the paper (Capitalized)
%tmplate used: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/mdpi-article-template/fcpwsspfzsph
\Title{Title}

% MDPI internal command: Title for citation in the left column
\TitleCitation{Title}

% Author Orchid ID: enter ID or remove command
\newcommand{\orcidauthorA}{0000-0000-0000-000X} % Add \orcidA{} behind the author's name
%\newcommand{\orcidauthorB}{0000-0000-0000-000X} % Add \orcidB{} behind the author's name

% Authors, for the paper (add full first names)
\Author{Firstname Lastname $^{1,\dagger,\ddagger}$\orcidA{}, Firstname Lastname $^{1,\ddagger}$ and Firstname Lastname $^{2,}$*}

% MDPI internal command: Authors, for metadata in PDF
\AuthorNames{Firstname Lastname, Firstname Lastname and Firstname Lastname}

% MDPI internal command: Authors, for citation in the left column
\AuthorCitation{Lastname, F.; Lastname, F.}
% If this is a Chicago style journal: Lastname, Firstname, Firstname Lastname, and Firstname Lastname.

% Affiliations / Addresses (Add [1] after \address if there is only one affiliation.)
\address{%
$^{1}$ \quad\\
$^{2}$ \quad Affiliation 2; e-mail@e-mail.com}

% Contact information of the corresponding author
\corres{Correspondence: ; Tel.: (optional; include country code; if there are multiple corresponding authors, add author initials) +xx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx (F.L.)}

% Current address and/or shared authorship
\firstnote{Current address: Affiliation 3} 
\secondnote{These authors contributed equally to this work.}

\preto{\abstractkeywords}{\nolinenumbers}

\begin{document}

\begin{specialtable}[ht] 
\caption{ABC.\label{tab1:ABC}}
\begin{tabularx}
{\columnwidth} { 
  | >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X 
  | >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X 
  | >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X |}
\toprule
\textbf{A}  & \textbf{B}    & \textbf{C}\\
\midrule
\begin{itemize} \item A1 \end{itemize}  &\begin{itemize} \item B1 \end{itemize} & \begin{itemize} \item C1 \end{itemize}\\
\begin{itemize} \item A2 \end{itemize} & \begin{itemize} \item B2 \end{itemize} & \begin{itemize} \item C2 \end{itemize}\\
\begin{itemize} \item A3 \end{itemize} & \begin{itemize} \item B3 \end{itemize} & \begin{itemize} \item C3 \end{itemize}\\
& \begin{itemize} \item B3 \end{itemize} & \begin{itemize} \item C4 \end{itemize}\\
& \begin{itemize} \item B4 \end{itemize} & \begin{itemize} \item C5 \end{itemize}\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{specialtable}
\end{document}
```

What can I do to fix this or is there an alternative way that gives me the expected output. Current output is attached. [image]

Comment: Substituting `specialtable` with the normal `table` environment and using the `article` class I can't reproduce your issue. Can you please post a complete example which we can compile? It should start with `\documentclass` and end at `\end{document}`, containing only what's necessary to reproduce your issue. Btw. if you're using the rules of `booktabs` (`\toprule`, `\midrule`, `\bottomrule`) you shouldn't use vertical rules.

Comment: Thank you I have added a complete example.

Comment: The complete template is taken from MDPI: https://www.overleaf.com/project/60c22d55152eae7a98f9fb3c

Comment: Sorry, your example rewuires an external file input and isn't compilable.

Comment: use tabularx not ltablex package

Comment: That was it! Thanks David. I removed the ltablex package and the error is gone.